# How to prevent the user from clicking in Python/Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

So I have made a game that creates questions and the user must guess the correct one. Every time the user gets a question correct a "correct!" appears but every time they get it wrong a "wrong!" appears. This text then fades away after 0.5 seconds.

When the user gets the question correct or wrong then the game waits for 0.5 seconds due to `time.sleep(0.5)`. The user can keep spamming mouse clicks and delay the program for several seconds as they can keep getting the question wrong.

This is the part of the code I need help with:

```
while answer != correct_answer:
        for event in pygame.event.get():         
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                for index, rect in enumerate(answers_rect):
                    if rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        answer = index
                        if answer == correct_answer:
                            display_text("correct!",green,(start_x-150),(start_y-650),medText)
                            pygame.display.update()
                            time.sleep(0.5)
                            display_text("correct!",white,(start_x-150),(start_y-650),medText)
                            pygame.display.update()
                        elif answer != correct_answer:
                            display_text("wrong!",red,(start_x-140),(start_y-650),medText)
                            pygame.display.update()
                            time.sleep(0.5)
                            display_text("wrong!",white,(start_x-140),(start_y-650),medText)
                            pygame.display.update()
```

How can I stop this spamming and for that 0.5 seconds not allow the user to click any answer?

Comment: Why don't you disable the button once it's clicked and re-enable it after sleep?

Comment: @helpmecode If you solved your issue, please mark one of the answers as accepted and upvote. Thanks and good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `waiting_for_sleep_to_over` global Boolean var.
Using this var, you can disable the clicks event like so:

```
waiting_for_sleep_to_over = False
while answer != correct_answer:
    for event in pygame.event.get():         
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and waiting_for_sleep_to_over is not True:
            for index, rect in enumerate(answers_rect):
                if rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    answer = index
                    if answer == correct_answer:
                        display_text("correct!",green,(start_x-150),(start_y-650),medText)
                        pygame.display.update()
                        waiting_for_sleep_to_over = True
                        time.sleep(0.5)
                        waiting_for_sleep_to_over = False
                        display_text("correct!",white,(start_x-150),(start_y-650),medText)
                        pygame.display.update()
                    elif answer != correct_answer:
                        display_text("wrong!",red,(start_x-140),(start_y-650),medText)
                        pygame.display.update()
                        waiting_for_sleep_to_over = True
                        time.sleep(0.5)
                        waiting_for_sleep_to_over = False
                        display_text("wrong!",white,(start_x-140),(start_y-650),medText)
                        pygame.display.update()
```

**EDIT:**
After the comment suggestion, instead of the boolean flag, use the following functions:
[pygame.event.set_blocked(pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN)](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.set_blocked)
[pygame.event.set_allowed(pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN)](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.set_allowed)

```
while answer != correct_answer:
    for event in pygame.event.get():         
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            for index, rect in enumerate(answers_rect):
                if rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    answer = index
                    if answer == correct_answer:
                        display_text("correct!",green,(start_x-150),(start_y-650),medText)
                        pygame.display.update()
                        pygame.event.set_blocked(pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN)
                        time.sleep(0.5)
                        pygame.event.set_allowed(pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN)
                        display_text("correct!",white,(start_x-150),(start_y-650),medText)
                        pygame.display.update()
                    elif answer != correct_answer:
                        display_text("wrong!",red,(start_x-140),(start_y-650),medText)
                        pygame.display.update()
                        pygame.event.set_blocked(pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN)
                        time.sleep(0.5)
                        pygame.event.set_allowed(pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN)
                        display_text("wrong!",white,(start_x-140),(start_y-650),medText)
                        pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: This won't work, the events are still added to the event queue when you click on the button.

Comment: @skrx have you tried this: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.set_blocked
So instead of the boolean var, try to use pygame.event.set_blocked() and pygame.event.set_allowed()

Comment: Seems to work with `pygame.event.set_blocked` and `set_allowed`. Better test the code yourself.

Comment: @skrx, Added your suggestion to the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome, Thank you!